# Can't add ssh key to the ssh agent

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to add my ssh key to the ssh agent but I always get the same error message, first I use root access by entering:
`sudo -s -H` ,then I enter my password an continue typing the next line: `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` in order to start the ssh-agent. No error messages so far, everything done correctly.
But the thing is that when I try to add the actual key with: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/key-id` *(where key-id is replaced with the name of the key)*, I get this error message: `/root/.ssh/key-id: No such file or directory`.

Here is the entire process:

```
sudo -s -H
[sudo] password for nulaxz:
[root@nulaxz-ms7a33 nulaxz]# eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 632477
[root@nulaxz-ms7a33 nulaxz]# ssh-add ~/.ssh/key-id
/root/.ssh/key-id: No such file or directory
```

I've tried using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/key-id`, `ssh-add ~/key-id` or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id-rsa/key-id` just in case, but all of them return the same error message.

Maybe I saved it in another location and I don't know, if so, how can I check it?

My main goal with this, is to connect Git and GitHub, I have been working a long time without them and I recently discovered Git, which really makes life easier, so I want to jump into GitHub aswell, so if anyone came across this error in the past and knows how to solve it, please let me know how you did it ;)

Comment: I'm half-wondering why you need your SSH keys available in a root shell.

Comment: Just followed git documentation xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your home directory (`~`) changes when you login as root, which means that you can't refer to the user's home directory just with the `~`, but you have to specify the whole path (e.g., `/home/yourusername/.ssh/key-id`).

Just execute your commands with sudo privileges, without root access.

Comment: Yeah, I executed them with sudo privileges and worked, thank you for your answer ;)